# Change rewritten URL back to URL variable using jQUERY

Tags: jquery, url-rewriting

Can I use a jQUERY script to check all links on my page and change

https://domain.nl/fotografie/emodule/5249/egallery/72157709983228136

into

https://domain.nl/fotografie/?emodule=5249&egallery=72157709983228136

where 5249 and 72157709983228136 are variable numbers

Comment: Yes you can, but you probably shouldn't. If someone has JS disabled, or clicks the link before the DOM fully loads (which can happen on slow loading sites) then the links will not be updated. Fix the issue at the source; either in your HTML directly, the datastore which generates the incorrect URLs, or alternatively use some method of URL rewriting on the server, such as .htacces

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, you are ofcourse right. But I struggled to find the correct settings in adjusting the exceptions (via regex) for rewriting the URL's.

Comment: I'd suggest starting a question about the regex in that case, as it's a *far* more preferable solution - assuming you're referring to .htaccess rules, that is.

Comment: I needed to add |/emodule/|/egallery/|/album/|/eitem/ in a specific Exceptions field